# java.util.InputMismatchException in my integer validation method

Tags: java

I get java.util.InputMismatchException every time a letter is entered. I'd like it to display the "incorrect message" instead of crashing. I tried making x a string and parsing the input, but the problem was still the same. Not quite sure how to do this. Here is my code:

```
public static void generateDivision() {

    Random rand4 = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard6 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int random = rand4.nextInt(12);
    int random2 = rand4.nextInt(12);

    //Following two lines ensures that no remainders are present so the numbers divide evenly.
    int n = random * random2;               
    int k  = n/random;                 

    System.out.println(n + " / " + random + " = ?");
    int x = keyboard6.nextInt();

    checkUserAnswer(k, x);
}   
public static void checkUserAnswer(int n, int x) {

    try {
        if (n == x) {

            System.out.println("Correct!");
            System.out.println();


        }
        if (n != x) {

            System.out.println("Incorrect!");
            System.out.println();


        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect! That was not a number.");

    } 
    updateStats(n, x);
    tryAgain();

    }
```

Comment: If only there was a way to try something and then catch exceptions and do something in those cases ... almost like what is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: I tried using a try-catch block but it still displays the error instead of printing an "incorrect" message

Comment: That is not the try/catch block's fault - the problem is how you coded it. We might be able to explain why that is the case if you showed us that code.

Comment: You didn't put the try block around the piece of code where you're getting input from the user which is where the problem is. The piece of code that can throw the error is what needs to go inside the try block. Your print statements are not going to throw input exceptions to be caught.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense actually. I was so focused on the method that checked numbers. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It's like "try to execute this error prone code and if it fails, catch the error" which in this case the error prone code is `keyboard6.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a try/catch block in your code for example:

```
try
{
   //Code to do 
}catch(InputMismatchException ex)
{
    System.out.print("Sorry, try entering another value");
}
```

You put all of your input code in the try block and if it fails you catch it with the catch block giving it the certain exception that you want in this case it's the InputMismatchException. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just tried doing this. When I tested it. The error still pops up, and my message does not display.

Comment: Can you post the code you have with the try catch block please?

Answer (score 0):

The function `nextInt()` always expects an `int` input, and will throw an exception if the user inputs something that is not an `int`.

You could use the `try-catch` syntax to catch the `InputMismatchException` and instead of throwing the exception, deliver a message to the user. Or, you could take user input as a `String` (perhaps `nextLine()`), and parse the `int` / give appropriate error messages yourself. However, there's no sense reinventing the wheel, so using `nextInt()`'s builtin parsing and `try-catch` is the cleaner option.

If you want an intro to handling exceptions with `try-catch`, [the Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) may be helpful.